# UnsupportedOperation: not writable when trying to run Python app server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, anaconda, pymysql

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Whenever I try to execute the above code the following error shows up:

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8f09ac2c0de3> in <module>()
    213 
    214 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 215     app.run_server()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py in run_server(self, port, debug, **flask_run_options)
    566                    debug=False,
    567                    **flask_run_options):
--> 568         self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
    936         options.setdefault('threaded', True)
    937 
--> 938         cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
    939 
    940         from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py in show_server_banner(env, debug, app_import_path, eager_loading)
    627             message += ' (lazy loading)'
    628 
--> 629         click.echo(message)
    630 
    631     click.echo(' * Environment: {0}'.format(env))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py in echo(message, file, nl, err, color)
    257 
    258     if message:
--> 259         file.write(message)
    260     file.flush()
    261 

UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Here I am connecting to a mysql server database which connects exactly as per credentials. Query is executed and read successfully into a dataframe. But when I try to run the server as stated above in line 1,2 it displays this error.

When I run this code in my colleagues machine, the server is hosted. 
I tried using multiple IDE's like PyCharm, Rodeo, Jupyter Notebook etc. but all gave me the same error.

I am using Python 3.6, 
Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Are you logging the (flask) server output?  If so, is the location of the logfile writeable?

Comment: I am showing you the console output. The log file is writable.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround can be found here:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/257

There are two options:

1. Go to your **'.../Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/click/'** folder and edit two *.py scripts

> ### utils.py script
>
> ***edit the echo function***
>
> Line 166 shows: `def echo(message=None, file=None, nl=True, err=False,color=None):`
>
> change to `def echo(message=None, file=sys.stdout, nl=True, err=False,color=None):`
>
> ### termui.py script
>
> ***edit the echo function***
>
> Line 408 shows: `def secho(text, file=None, nl=True, err=False,color=None, **styles):`
>
> change to `def secho(text, file=sys.stdout,nl=True, err=False, color=None, **styles):`

2. **Downgrade Flask**: `conda install flask=0.12.2`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I overcame this problem by reinstalling python 3.7 in the system. I appreciate your concern towards the problem

Answer (score 0):

By editing the source in the source in the site-packages the changes will be overridden on any update, so I don't like that workaround.

Rather bypass the issue by calling the werkzeug service directly instead of using the Flask run function.
(Just note that this also bypass some config option that you will now have to set yourself)

Use this to run on localhost with port 8080

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from flask import Flask

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=Flask(__name__)
    run_simple('localhost', 8080, app)
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a problem when trying to run through Jupyter notebook. Try copying the code to a notepad file and try running it from a terminal. Should work.

Comment: More like a comment, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it did work for me in ipython. The jupyter notebook is not a right choice while building an webapp using flask. You also try using different IDE other than jupyter.